# Make a coin be unfair in java

Tags: java

I need to make a coin unfair, by making it show heads twice as much as tails. I don't currently know where to begin with turning the flip() class, so that it shows heads twice as much as tails. What I'm asking is what is the algorithm that I would have to implement in order to have heads show twice as often as tails?

Here is the coin file:

```
public class Coin {
     private final int HEADS = 0;
     private boolean face;

    public Coin() {
        flip();
    }

    public void flip() {
        face = ((int) (Math.random() * 2) != 0);
    }

    public boolean isHeads() {
        return face;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return (isHeads()) ? "Heads" : "Tails";
    }
}
```

And here is the CountFilps file:

```
public class CoinFlips {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int FLIPS = 1000;
        int heads = 0, tails = 0;

        Coin myCoin = new Coin();

        for (int count = 1; count <= FLIPS; count++) {
            myCoin.flip();

            if (myCoin.isHeads()) {
                heads++;
            } else {
                tails++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Number of flips: " + FLIPS);
        System.out.println("Number of heads: " + heads);
        System.out.println("Number of tails: " + tails);
    }
}
```

Edit: Thanks everyone for the quick responses! I feel silly for not knowing that was all I needed to do.

Comment: Fair is one tails chance in `2`. You're looking for one chance in `3`.

Comment: heads when `math.random()` is between 0.000 and 0.6667, else tails

Answer (score 6):

```
Random rand = new Random();
int value = rand.nextInt(3); // Possible values are 0, 1 & 2

if(value == 0) {
   System.out.println("heads");
} else { 
   System.out.println("tail");
}
```

Fair is a 50% chance. Unfair is anything different from 50% chance (1 out of 3 = 33% chance).

Comment: Correction: Possible values  = 0,1,2.  Your 33% still holds, but the explanation is slightly incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Replace flip() with this:

```
face = (Math.random() >= 1/3.0);
```

Hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Nitpick: `1/3` evaluates to 0.

Comment: huh? what do you mean? 1/3 = 0.3333333333

Answer (score 2):

Change your `flip()` method to

```
face = ((int) (Math.random() * 3) < 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change your flip method to look like the following

```
public void flip() {
    face = ((int) (Math.random() * 3) != 0);
}
```

This would make the coin be heads 66.6% percent of the time, theoretically, and tails 33.3%.

Of course you can switch your true/false logic to make tails 66.6% and heads 33.3%.

You can change the `3` to any number, using 5 would make tails 80% and heads 20%.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following flip method.

```
public void flip() {
    face = (Math.random() >= 1.0 / 3.0);
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: `1/3` evaluates to 0.